# Can the Pi 3 model B output 5v at 1a?

Tags: power

Im looking to build a portable retropie system using the pi 3 model b and some adafruit hdmi screen + audio. The adafruit monitor and audio call for 5v at 936 mah, so is there anyway to power that directly off of the pie?

I plan on using an anker 20100 mah power bank which can do 2.4a at 5v to power the pie, but I would like to have everything be powered only by that one port because the bank is going to be removable and I only want one connection

Comment: *"anker 20100 mah power bank which can do 2.4a at 5v"* -> Don't count on it.  Power banks are intended for recharging batteries, a task which is antithetical to powering a live device where sudden spikes in current draw may occur (which would be *bad* in the context of recharging a battery).   I have a few power banks, one of them is about that size and rated at 2.5 amps, but none of them will power a Pi 3 *alone* without the red led flickering (indicating under voltage as a consequence of sudden current draw by the SoC).

Comment: Put another way: You will need circuitry intended for powering a live device, which a power bank does not provide.  Adafruit sells such things though.  If you are going to do that you might as well power the monitor etc. independently.

Answer (score 1):

Given the capacity and the ratings of the power bank, it should work.You won't be very far from the limits though.

The problem with the Pi and battery applications is that the Pi is not designed to support a battery. In boards with battery support (such as Banana Pi / Orange Pi IoT / Odroid C0 / Odroid GO / X300), the core voltages (3.3/1.5V) are derived directly from the battery voltage (3.7V), without going up to 5V first. Voltage boost involves losses and delays, so sudden current spikes easily lead to undervoltage events. With a Pi, you will be limited by 2.4A with your huge 20 A·h battery, which alone could easily supply 40A at 3.7V during a short spike.

Needless to say, a portable device becomes much more portable if you can put a 3 A·h battery in it (like Odroid GO which weights only 180 grams) instead of a 20 A·h powerbank.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Pi3B can supply 1 amp at 5V with the following proviso:-

The current consumed by the Pi itself and other peripherals connected is less than the polyfuse rating (2.2amp?) less 1 amp.